# "Missing Authentication Token" trying to perform a Post to AWS api

Tags: amazon-web-services, api

There have been loads of topics on this error and I've spent hours reading through them.  I am getting this error when trying to load the URL of my Post method (it works fine when I test it within the AWS console).  When I run the URL created after I deployed it:

https://somehexvalues.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/temperature

I get this errror:  message "Missing Authentication Token"

I can see the response contained this error:  missingAuthenticationTokenException

I've done the exact same thing with a Get and had no problems. Is this something specific to Post?

- I deployed the app after every change and took the URL from the method's STAGES tab.
- Validation and authentication are set to "None"

Is there anything else I can do to debug this?

Comment: It's really not clear from this post which AWS services you are working with.

Comment: If you're trying to click on the URL it's not going to return the data you think it will. Whenever you visit an endpoint in the browser it defaults to a GET request. You need to test your endpoint using something like Postman or cURL in terminal.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanWong, that was in fact the problem.  I had also tried it using SoapUI but apparently that wasn't appropriate for this kind of endpoint.